# Close port using Tornado web server

Tags: python, port, tornado

I am running a Tornado web server to send GET and POST requests. I want to be able to shut it down to do modifications on it and start it when finished to test it. But I cant, the port used is in used forever...

```
def startTornado():
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(80)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    print "Server is running"

def stopTornado():
    ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    ioloop.add_callback(ioloop.stop)
    print "Asked Tornado to exit"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #stopTornado()
    startTornado()
```

I checked all the answer on the web, but I it doesnt help me.

```
ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
ioloop.add_callback(ioloop.stop)
```

Doesnt close the port. It is still in use :

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80            PC-1:0            LISTENING
[python.exe]
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

To close the port, you must call `HTTPServer.close()`, not `IOLoop.stop()` (a stopped `IOLoop` can be restarted). This means using

```
server = HTTPServer(application)
server.listen(80)
```

instead of the `Application.listen` convenience method.